# iOS Metal. How do I use the 'half' format for all color work?

Tags: ios, metal, openexr

The default color format for an `MTKView` is `bgra8Unorm`. I prefer to use the `half` format (See: OpenEXR). I am unclear which of the various formats Metal provides corresponds to `half`?

Comment: Using HDR images somewhere in your rendering doesn't necessarily imply the use of an HDR drawable. No current iOS device has a display with 16-bit per component color depth, so clipping is going to occur for values outside the 0-1 range if you copy from an HDR texture to your drawable. The usual way to deal with this is to apply a tonemapping process that compresses values back into the gamut. Your drawable can still be `.bgra8unorm` (or `.bgra10_xr` when appropriate). For rendering operations that require higher precision or high dynamic range, you can still use intermediate 16-bit textures.

Comment: Thanks Warren. I am moving to a linear rendering pipeline. In addition I am an OpenEXR - half based - fan and like very much the concept of "deep textures" used at ILM and elsewhere. I am a bit unclear on your conclusion. So, I can be "half-based" throughout as long as I tone-map (or gamma correct) before writing to the device framebuffer?

Comment: One more thing. In my MTKView sublclass I have set colorPixelFormat = .rgba16Float. Based on your comment I am now confused as to what exactly have I set use rgba16Float here.

Comment: Tone-mapping and gamma correction serve different purposes. You might want to read up on topics in [HDR](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/HDR) before proceeding too far down this path, but to answer your question, yes, you can use 16-bit textures throughout your pipeline and apply tone-mapping as a postprocess when doing your final pass.

Comment: yep, sounds good.

Comment: Warren, one non-obvious thing I noticed by just swapping in `.rgba16Float` for the default `.bgra8unorm` for the `MTKView` is all textures are significantly brighter/washed-out. Is there a gamma applied using `.bgra8unorm` that is turned off when I switch to `.rgba16Float`? Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`rgb16Float`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlpixelformat/rgba16float):

> Ordinary format with four 16-bit floating-point components in RGBA order.

Comment: Keep in mind that reading and writing 16 bit float values when using intermediate textures is 2x as slow when compared to using sRGB encoded textures. There is a slight precision issue when using gamma corrected values mapped into the 8 bit range, but the execution time is about twice as fast when compared to reading and writing 16 bit float values.